# Distinct on custom types

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to use Distinct on the following custom class:

```
public class RightOperandValue : IEquatable<RightOperandValue>
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public int GetHashCode(RightOperandValue obj)
    {
        int hashValue = Value == null ? 0 : Value.GetHashCode();
        int hashDisplayName = DisplayName == null ? 0 : DisplayName.GetHashCode();

        return hashValue ^ hashDisplayName;
    }

    public bool Equals(RightOperandValue other)
    {
        if (Value.Equals(other.Value)
            && DisplayName.Equals(other.DisplayName))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the distinct values of the property Person.City which are "CITY" and "City     ".

I try the following:

```
        var values = _context
            .Persons
            .Select(x=>x.City)
            .ToList();

        var rovs = values
              .Select(x => new RightOperandValue() { DisplayName = x.Trim().ToLowerInvariant(), Value = x.Trim().ToLowerInvariant() })
              .Distinct()
              .OrderBy(x => x.DisplayName)
              .ToList();
        return rovs;
```

Which gives two instances of RightOperandValue that have "city" for the value of DisplayName and Value.

I know this seems like a roundabout way to do things, but I ultimately need Distinct to work on this custom class RightOperandValue. I read that implementing GetHashCode and Equals are the way to do it, but it does not seem to work

Comment: I've read this twice and I still have no idea what you are asking.  Maybe its just me, but you may want to clean your question up a bit

Comment: I am also confused by the question. My brain is telling you to look at functions like .Trim(), .ToUpper(), or .String.Compare()

Comment: Ok I'll try to clean it up. Ya it was a bit unruly, sorry.

Comment: @maccettura hopefully the edit makes it more readable.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `Distinct` <s>does not use `Equals`</s> uses `Equals` **and** `GetHashCode`. Except it is not going to use your custom implementation (I'm not sure if you were trying to override `GetHashCode` there). You need to override `GetHashCode` with this method signature:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    // Your hashing algorithm here.
}
```

<s>Your current hashing algorithm is no good as it stands though. If `Value` and `DisplayName` are the same they will result in the same hash. When you XOR the same hashes together you will get 0.</s>

Comment: "The issue is that Distinct does not use Equals it uses GetHashCode" - no, it uses both. And while an XOR hash isn't great, it will still work. (It will work precisely *because* Equals is used as well as GetHashCode.)

Comment: @Jason Boyd, see [this remarks on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks). Quoting it "Two objects that are equal return hash codes that are equal. However, the reverse is not true: equal hash codes do not imply object equality, because different (unequal) objects can have identical hash codes". `return 0;` is a valid implementation for `GetHashCode`;not that should be implemented that way, of course: a good hash function is quick an give (possibly) different results for different input and (mandatory) same result for the same input

Comment: It *is* true that the OP's hashing algorithm isn't very good.  The consequences of the not-good hash is that it's slower than it could be if a better one was used, and it will be slower because more objects (on average) will need to use the `Equals` method.  The poor hash doesn't stop it from producing the correct results.

Comment: @Jason, note also that collisions on Hash codes are inevitable: GetHashCode returns an integer, i.e.2^32 different values: when you apply GetHashCode to the virtually infinite number of different strings, you will get collisions

Answer (score 1):

Issue was I was not implementing IEquatable correctly

```
public class RightOperandValue : IEquatable<RightOperandValue> 
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(RightOperandValue other)
    {
        if (Value == other.Value
            && DisplayName == other.DisplayName)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hashValue = Value == null ? 0 : Value.GetHashCode();
        int hashDisplayName = DisplayName == null ? 0 : DisplayName.GetHashCode();

        return hashValue ^ hashDisplayName;
    }

}
```

Comment: As an aside, your `Equals` method would be more simply return as `return Value == other.Value && DisplayName == other.DisplayName;` - at which case you can implement it with an expression-bodied member.